# Return values from exe in javascript

Tags: asp.net, scripting, javascript

i have to call an executable in the client machine in asp.net and get the return parameters, i been looking for an example but i couldn't find it.

it this possible to recover the output parameters from one exe in JavaScript?

i know that can i write:

var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var oExec = WshShell.Exec("My.exe");

but the clients executable returns 0 or 1 that values are the ones i need to collect

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't read the client file system from the browser. You certainly can't launch an .exe. What is the .exe doing? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @John Saunders can you not script an ActiveXObject to run WScript.Shell? I agree it is fraught with difficulties and should not be done so maybe a clearer description of what is needed will provide a better solution

Comment: @Pharabus: yeah, if you call that a solution!

Comment: @John Saunders I definately don't :) I just wanted to clarify that it is "possible" to call client exe's of a fashion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browser-based JavaScript can't call executable files on client machines; to do so would be a catastrophic security problem. If you have to run an executable on the client machine, consider asking the user to install a .NET application, an ActiveX control, or something like Java if you want to be platform-independent.

Depending on what you're trying to do, you may not need to run an EXE on the client machine; you can do a LOT with standard cloud-type scenarios (JS or SilverLight on the client, Web services or WCF on the server). Without more information about your situation, however, it's impossible to tell.

**EDIT:** Based on your comments that you're using the `ActiveXObject.Exec` method, you can use the `StdOut` property of the `WshScriptExec` object that method returns. From [MSDN's article on the StdOut property:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cbxxzwb5%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
      if (!oExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream)
      {
           input += oExec.StdOut.Read(1);
           //...
      }
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure the java runtime could do this from within a browser either.

Comment: @Chris Lively: You may well be right. I don't know Java as well as .NET, but it would certainly make sense if that wasn't allowed.

Comment: Hi again, im developing a button that needs to call an executable in the client machine, this is validated by the users and they agree to allow that... i can do: var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
                var oExec = WshShell.Exec("my.exe") but i need to collect the results returned by it...

Comment: @kode keeper: I think your going to have to pipe the results from the exe to a file, then try to read that file from your script.